# SQLAlchemy - pass a dynamic tablename to query function?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a simple polling script that polls entries based on new ID's in a MSSQL table. I'm using `SQLAlchemy`'s ORM to create a table class and then query that table. I want to be able to add more tables "dynamically" without coding it directly into the method.

My polling function:

```
def poll_db():
    query = db.query(
        Transactions.ID).order_by(Transactions.ID.desc()).limit(1)

    # Continually poll for new images to classify
    max_id_query = query

    last_max_id = max_id_query.scalar()
    
    while True:

        max_id = max_id_query.scalar()
        if max_id > last_max_id:
            print(
                f"New row(s) found. "
                f"Processing ids {last_max_id + 1} through {max_id}"
            )
            # Insert ML model
            id_query = db.query(Transactions).filter(
                Transactions.ID > last_max_id)

            df_from_query = pd.read_sql_query(
                id_query.statement, db.bind, index_col='ID')

            print(f"New query was made")

            last_max_id = max_id
        time.sleep(5)
```

My table model:

```
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import defer, relationship, query

from database import SessionLocal, engine

insp = db.inspect(engine)
db_list = insp.get_schema_names()

Base = declarative_base(cls=BaseModel)

class Transactions(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'simulation_data'
    sender_account = db.Column('sender_account', db.BigInteger)
    recipient_account = db.Column('recipient_account', db.String)
    sender_name = db.Column('sender_name', db.String)
    recipient_name = db.Column('recipient_name', db.String)
    date = db.Column('date', db.DateTime)
    text = db.Column('text', db.String)
    amount = db.Column('amount', db.Float)
    currency = db.Column('currency', db.String)
    transaction_type = db.Column('transaction_type', db.String)
    fraud = db.Column('fraud', db.BigInteger)
    swift_bic = db.Column('swift_bic', db.String)
    recipient_country = db.Column('recipient_country', db.String)
    internal_external = db.Column('internal_external', db.String)
    ID = Column('ID', db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
```

**QUESTION**

How can I pass the table class name "dynamically" in the likes of `poll_db(tablename)`, where `tablename='Transactions'`, and instead of writing similar queries for multiple tables, such as:

```
query = db.query(Transactions.ID).order_by(Transactions.ID.desc()).limit(1)       


query2 = db.query(Transactions2.ID).order_by(Transactions2.ID.desc()).limit(1)
        

query3 = db.query(Transactions3.ID).order_by(Transactions3.ID.desc()).limit(1)
```

The tables will have identical structure, but different data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you a full example right now (will edit later) but here's one hacky way to do it (the documentation will probably be a better place to check):

```py
def dynamic_table(tablename):
    for class_name, cls in Base._decl_class_registry.items():
        if cls.__tablename__ == tablename:
            return cls

Transactions2 = dynamic_table("simulation_data")
assert Transactions2 is Transactions
```

The returned class is the model you want. Keep in mind that `Base` can only access the tables that have been subclassed already so if you have them in other modules you need to import them first so they are registered as `Base`'s subclasses.

For selecting columns, something like this should work:

```py
def dynamic_table_with_columns(tablename, *columns):
    cls = dynamic_table(tablename)
    subset = []
    for col_name in columns:
        column = getattr(cls, col_name)
        if column:
            subset.append(column)
    
    # in case no columns were given
    if not subset:
        return db.query(cls)

    return db.query(*subset)
```

Comment: Thanks - will try to adapt this to my current work. If it works, I'll accept the answer :-)

Comment: Just noticed that you edited the answer. If you want to only get some columns maybe you can change your `dynamic_table`'s signature. I'll edit that in